# How to insert pspicture in article

Tags: pdf, winedt, pspicture

I unable to run the following code. How to resolve it. Now i am using Miktex 2.9. and Winedt. Kindly help me to resolve it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath,latexsym,amssymb,amsthm,enumerate}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{pst-pdf,pst-text,pstricks-add}
\begin{document} \begin{center}
\scalebox{1} % Change this value to rescale the drawing.
{
\begin{pspicture}(0,-1.08)(3.76,1.08)
\psdots[dotsize=0.12](0.06,0.2)
\psdots[dotsize=0.12](0.86,0.2)
\psdots[dotsize=0.12](1.66,0.2)
\psdots[dotsize=0.12](2.48,0.22)
\psdots[dotsize=0.12](3.28,0.2)
\psdots[dotsize=0.12](0.06,-1.0)
\psdots[dotsize=0.12](0.88,-1.0)
\psdots[dotsize=0.12](1.68,-1.0)
\psdots[dotsize=0.12](2.48,-1.0)
\psdots[dotsize=0.12](3.26,-1.0)
\psdots[dotsize=0.12](0.48,1.0)
\psdots[dotsize=0.12](1.28,1.0)
\psdots[dotsize=0.12](2.08,1.0)
\psdots[dotsize=0.12](2.88,1.0)
\psdots[dotsize=0.12](3.68,1.0)
\psline[linewidth=0.02cm](0.04,0.22)(0.04,-0.96)
\psline[linewidth=0.02cm](0.06,-0.98)(1.7,-0.98)
\psline[linewidth=0.02cm](0.86,0.22)(0.86,-1.0)
\psline[linewidth=0.02cm](1.66,0.18)(1.66,-0.94)
\psline[linewidth=0.02cm](0.06,0.24)(0.46,1.0)
\psline[linewidth=0.02cm](0.84,0.26)(0.46,1.06)
\psline[linewidth=0.02cm](0.88,0.22)(1.28,1.02)
\psline[linewidth=0.02cm](1.66,0.22)(1.26,1.06)
\psline[linewidth=0.02cm](1.66,0.24)(2.06,1.04)
\psline[linewidth=0.02cm](2.46,0.24)(2.46,-0.98)
\psline[linewidth=0.02cm](2.46,-0.98)(3.22,-0.98)
\psline[linewidth=0.02cm](3.28,0.24)(3.28,-0.98)
\psline[linewidth=0.02cm](2.48,0.24)(2.88,1.02)
\psline[linewidth=0.02cm](2.86,1.02)(3.28,0.18)
\psline[linewidth=0.02cm](3.68,1.02)(3.28,0.22)
\psline[linewidth=0.02cm](0.46,1.02)(2.06,1.02)
\psline[linewidth=0.02cm](2.86,1.02)(3.68,1.02)
\psline[linewidth=0.02cm,linestyle=dashed,dash=0.16cm 0.16cm](2.08,1.02)(2.84,1.02)
\psline[linewidth=0.02cm,linestyle=dashed,dash=0.16cm 0.16cm](2.08,1.0)(2.44,0.24)
\psline[linewidth=0.02cm,linestyle=dashed,dash=0.16cm 0.16cm](1.7,-1.0)(2.44,-1.0)
\end{pspicture}
}

Figure 1.
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the error? No problem here using TeXlive 2014 on Linux.

Comment: I used many pictures like this so I unable identify the error. In my out put the text and equations are appeared but the images are not

Comment: Are you running `latex` and getting the `dvi` file? You can not compile directly with `pdflatex`, you need to convert from DVI to PS and then to PDF.

Comment: How to convert this I dont know how

Comment: On log file you will find: *Package pst-pdf Warning:* and around it there is some help.

Comment: also unrelated but don't load the `epsfig` package. It was produced in 1993 to emulate a package that was old _then_.

Comment: Or you can use Winedt to change the compiler to run `latex` and then use the toolbar to find the convertors. I don't use it so I don't know the shortcuts.

Comment: I am not clear if you dont mind kindly comment the step wise procedure

Comment: In WinEdt, from the dropdown button of compilers, choose 'LaTeX' and compile. Then press the button on its right 'DVIPS' and at last press the button 'ps2pdf'.

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: Dear friends, Thank you its work in ordinary article class bur i am using cej.cls (central european journal) (available on https://svn.kwarc.info/repos/arXMLiv/trunk/sty/cej.cls). Kindly help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can compile your code with `pdflatex`, provided you enable the `--enable-write18` switch via `Execution Modes` in the `Options`menu:
[image]

You also have to add `pdf` option to the document class. I took the opportunity to simplify your code , using the `multido` package. I took the liberty to slightly change the values of some coordinates which looked weird, so as to be able to pragram the points, rather than having to typeset them, one after another. Here is the shorter code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,pdf, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pst-text,pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    %\scalebox{1}{ % Change this value to rescale the drawing.
    \begin{pspicture}(0,-1.08)(3.76,1.08)
        \psset{dotsize=0.12,linewidth=0.02cm}
        \multido{\n=0.06+0.80,\N = 0.48 + 0.80,\i =1 +1}{5}
        {\dotnodes(\n, 0.2){A\i}(\n, -1.0){B\i}
            \dotnodes(\N, 1.0){C\i}
            \psline(B\i)(A\i)(C\i)
        }
        \psline(A2)(C1)(C3)\psline(A5)(C4)(C5)\psline(A3)(C2)
        \psline(B1)(B3)\psline(B4)(B5)
        \psset{linestyle=dashed,dash=0.16cm 0.16cm}
        \psline(A4)(C3)(C4)
        \psline(B3)(B4)
    \end{pspicture}
    %}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Bernard, Thank you its work in ordinary article class bur i am using cej.cls (central european journal) (available on https://svn.kwarc.info/repos/arXMLiv/trunk/sty/cej.cls). Kindly help me.